# How do I add subsections to accordion and only have one section collapsible at any one time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I am trying to create an accordion for use in my website and I am trying to achieve 2 things:

1) I only want one section to be expanded at any one time e.g. If "Introduction" is expanded, it collapses when I select the "Customers" or "Commercial" section.

What needs to be added to the javascript to achieve this?

2)  Within the "Customers" section I am trying to add other collapsible sections called "Unit 1", "Unit 2", "Unit 3" etc.

How do I create a subsection?

Any help with the above would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Frank

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Frank's Accordion</h2>
<p>Select a section..</p>

<button class="accordion">Introduction</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Customers</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Commercial</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Frank, this should probably be two questions, and at a minimum, you need to show us you made an attempt at creating the sub-sections.

Answer (score 0):

I have only answered your first question, because I think you need to make an attempt at the second question before we can help. We don't want to right the code for you :)

I have basically add another `for` loop inside the `onClick` event to check if any of the accordions have a class of "active" and if they do, collapse them. I imagine this code could be simplified.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

// check if element has class function
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

// accordion function
function accordion(element) {
  element.classList.toggle("active");
  var panel = element.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel.style.maxHeight){
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    // loop through accordion elements again
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      // check if any of the element have a class of "active" and is not the currently clicked element
      if ( hasClass(acc[i], "active") &&  acc[i] != this) {
        // collapse any already opened accordions
        accordion(acc[i]);
      }
    }
    // toggle clicked accordion
    accordion(this);
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Frank's Accordion v1.1</h2>
<p>Select a section..</p>

<button class="accordion">Introduction</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Customers</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Commercial</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```